# How can I check the status of a subscription using in_app_purchase?

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I cannot find up-to-date information on how to find out the current status of a subscription, i.e. check whether it is active or inactive.

I expect to get as a result the ability to identify whether a user has their subscription active or inactive.